# White space from datatable screenshot in Rmarkdown PDF

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

i am facing a problem with the new possibility of taking a screenshot of html widgets for further implementation, in for example pdf document. The screenshot of the `datatable` (`DT` package) has too high height, which appears as a white space in `rmarkdown` document (it is easily spotted by the position of the `fig.cap`, that is way below the end of the `datatable`).i cannot understand why is this happening and i would like to **remove it** (no white space under the `datatable`). Have a look at the example below for the `test.Rmd` which fully shows the problem:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
---
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\chead{Test}
\lhead{\scriptsize\today}


```{r, fig.align='center', fig.pos='htb!', fig.width=12, fig.cap="The height of screenshot is too high!!",fig.height=3,echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
datatable(mtcars[1:2,],rownames=FALSE, options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
```
````

[image]

- Additionally i have tried different number of displayed rows in `datatable`, and i have noticed if the `datatable` **has > 20** rows then figure is **well displayed** with the caption.
- However my table in original pdf file has for example **2 rows** (**can be bit more** --> the number of rows is reactive, as this `rmarkdown` is a downloable report that belongs to `shiny app`), thats why in example i have used only two rows from `mtcars` dataset.

Comment: Are you on mac or windows or...?  Can you post results of devtools::session_info()?

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hello @AK88 no,unfortunatelly  i did not manage to find the right solution

Comment: Maybe open an issue on github? https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues

Comment: @AK88 I think it is likely to be an issue with `DT::datatable()`. I am running into this issue in a Shiny app. I'm rendering it as `renderUI` instead of `renderDataTable` (because I'm doing it in a loop with different types of UI objects rendering), and I am getting a lot of white space below, too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add the following to `r chunk` and see if this works:

```
screenshot.opts = list(delay = 1, cliprect = c(0, 0, 1000, 150)), dev='jpeg'
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a good idea, however there is one problem, this code crops the image (fixed height), but what if my image will more rows (3 and not 2)? This happens as this `rmarkdown` is downloable report from shiny app

Comment: I believe you will have to adjust the `height` of the cropped image. I think this screenshot function works well with `html` format, but with PDF its not ideal. As you can see, I set `dev='jpeg'`. If you leave that out (default will be PDF) then you wont be able to get rid off the white space. Anyway, have a look at here: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/313 and here: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/313 for some more color.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in a Shiny app using `renderUI` to render a `datatable` object. I had to add `width = 100%` and `height = 100%`. So maybe try:

```
datatable(mtcars[1:2, ], rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = "t", ordering = F), height = "100%")
```

Answer (score 0):

On the webpage from which you are grabbing the table, is there a CSS selector?  If you can find one that encloses just the table it may just grab the table and not a shot of the whole page.  See this example:

```
webshot("http://www.nfl.com/superbowl/results/superbowl/", "nfl.png",
         selector = "div.columnStats")
```

To find the CSS selector, I went to the webpage  ( in this case http://www.nfl.com/superbowl/results/superbowl/) in a browser and then hit Ctrl+u to view the source.  I scrolled until I found the table and on line 1374 found

```
<!-- Records table -->
    <div class="columnStats">
```

I translated `div class="columnStats"` into the option `div.columnStats`, which I specified for selector.

**Windows**

I was able to reproduce your error.  In your actual application is there a CSS selector you can specify?  (see NFL example above).

**MAC**

No problems with whitespace.  Here's what I did:

I had never used `DT`, `webshot`, or PhantomJS.  So after:

```
install.packages("DT")
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

I knit'd the test.Rmd you posted **on my mac** and got:

[image]

Comment: Hi @swihart, table is rendered in Rmarkdown, so there is no webpage. Second: My R is installed on the linux Server